# Create deep entity without deep structure

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-gateway

I want to pass an amount of storage units in one step. I need all storage units at once in the `CREATE_ENTITY` method in my OData service implementation (`CREATE_ENTITY`, or `CREATE_DEEP_ENTITY`, or...?), because I have to make a comparison of some values.

I tried a batch request. This doesn't work, because the `CREATE_ENTITY` method was called for each storage unit. So I could access only one storage unit in each call.

I also searched for tutorials concerning `deep_entities`. But I only find some with deep structures (head - items). But I have a flat structure (key: storage Unit) and want to pass this as table/array to my `CREATE_ENTITY` method. It should be possible to do this in SAPUI5.

As workaround I could pass all storage units into a string and pass this to the `CREATE_ENTITY` method. But that seems quite amateurish to me.

Here is how I invoke `CREATE` method:

```js
onStartVert: function () {
    this.oContext = this.getModel().createEntry("/LenumIPunktSet", {
        success: this._successSave.bind(this),
        error: this._errorSave.bind(this)
    });
    var oBindingPath = {
        path: this.oContext.getPath()
    };
    this.getView().bindObject(oBindingPath);
    var sLenum;
    for (var i = 0; i < this._data.LePool.length; i++) {
        sLenum = this._data.LePool[i].lenum;
        this.getModel().create("/LenumIPunktSet", {
            lenum: sLenum
        });
    }
    this.getModel().submitChanges();
    this.getRouter().navTo("iPunkt02");
},
```

The signature for the `CHANGESET_PROCESS` method is:

```
CT_CHANGESET_DATA   TYPE /IWBEP/IF_MGW_CORE_SRV_RUNTIME=>TY_T_CHANGESET_DATA    
/IWBEP/CX_MGW_BUSI_EXCEPTION        Business Exception
/IWBEP/CX_MGW_TECH_EXCEPTION        Technical Exception
```

So, by now there is no table `IT_CHANGESET_REQUEST` available.
My entity type has only this one field (`lenum`) I need as key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to implement a changeset.

In your `DPC_EXT` redefine the following three methods:

---

The method **`CHANGESET_BEGIN`** will activate the batch processing.

```
METHOD /iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_begin.
    cv_defer_mode = 'X'.
ENDMETHOD.
```

```
METHOD /iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_end.
* empty
ENDMETHOD.
```

The method **`changeset_process`** will contain the logic. **`it_changeset_request`** contains all entities which are part of this batch request.

```
METHOD /iwbep/if_mgw_appl_srv_runtime~changeset_process.
    LOOP AT it_changeset_request ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_changeset_request>).
        " <fs_changeset_request>-request_context->get_request_details( ) << which entity is it?
        " <fs_changeset_request>-operation_type << is it CREATE, UPDATE or DELETE?
        " <fs_changeset_request>-entry_provider->read_entry_data( ... ) << read entity into structure
    ENDLOOP.
ENDMETHOD.
```

See [this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/03/09/how-to-implement-odata-batch-processing-with-content-id-in-sap-gateway/#a4) for some details.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I implemented these methods, but it seems that in method "changeset_process" I there is only a changing table "it_changeset_data" available. And this one is empty. Do you have any idea what I made worng?

Comment: How do you trigger the CREATE in the frontend? Can you update your question? If everything is set up correctly then every create call will be bundled into a single $batch request (you can see this in the network tab). Then in the backend `it_changeset_request ` should contain all created (or updated or deleted) entities.

Comment: Sorry, there is a little mistake in the comment above and I cant change it anymore:
In method _/iwbep/if_mgw_core_srv_runtime~changeset_process_  is a changing table _CT_CHANGESET_DATA_ . And this one is empty when I watch at it in debugger. I dont find many information regarding this table. Only _it_changeset_request_, but this one is not available as importing or changing parameter.

Comment: Ah I see your problem. Yes, `changeset_process` exists twice. First from the interface `/IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME`. Second from the interface `/IWBEP/IF_MGW_CORE_SRV_RUNTIME`. Use the **first** one (as can be seen in my answer). It will contain the importing parameters. Also use the **first** one for `changeset_begin` and `changeset_process`.

Comment: Ah ok, I changed it. I don't see yet that this methods which I just redefined are called. But I will go on trying. Many many thanks for your help. Let me know if I can show my appreciation!

Comment: Did you delete the "wrong" changeset_begin/process/end?

Comment: No, not yet. I will delete the wrong definitions ASAP and give feedback. Thank you!